# Samba server - files created as user root instead of normal user

Tags: debian, samba

I have a Debian Wheezy with a Samba (3.6) server installed with a `/share` folder, and I don't know why but files get created as user **root** instead of **user** (uid=1000), here is my conf:

```
[global]
        server string = %h server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

[share]
        comment = my share
        path = /share
        valid users = user
        admin users = user
        write list = user
        force user = user
        force group = user
        read only = No
        create mask = 0660
        directory mask = 0660
```

I tried **force user = user** and **force group = user** but it doesn't look like it worked...

On my windows machine, when I create a file I get:

```
$ la /share
-rw-rw---- 1 root user       0 Jun  2 10:52 testfile.txt
```

Any insight appreciated :-)

Comment: Just to confirm, you are logging in as `user` and the directory `/share` is writable by `user`?

Comment: Yes, the rights on the directory are `drwxr-xr-x   5 user nogroup  4096 Jun  2 10:52 share`

Comment: Do you get the same result without any kind of 'force' option?

Comment: Yes, same result.

Answer (score 4):

It is a mix of two items

```
admin users = user
force user = user
```

The first causes files created by user to be owned by root, the second causes all users to act as if there were user.

Remove admin users = user and then make sure that /share has read/write for the user user.